# Measure Theory - Proving $m_*(X)$ splits for disjoint unions in (compact case).

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The following question is based on Stein and Shakarchi's *Real Analyis - Measure Theory etc.*

---

(Theorem 3.2, pg.19)
If $E := \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}E_i$, where all $E_i$ are (Lebesgue) measurable sets and are all mutually disjoint, then
$$m(E) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}m(E_i).$$

---

The proof goes in two directions ($\leq$ and $\geq$), the first of which is provided by the infimum in the definition of exterior measure, we call this case Countable Sub-Additivity.

The proof of the other case requires some lemmas. First off, one must prove that measurability of a set is preserved through complements (seperate problem). That is, $E$ measurable implies $E^c$ measurable.

Measurability of complements allows us to find closed subsets $F_i\subseteq E_i$ inside our union constituents whose set differences $E_i-F_i$ have arbitrarily small measure.

Now, ignoring the general case which can be reduced in the later part of the argument, we further assume the constituent $E_i$ are *bounded*, making the $F_i$ both *closed and bounded* hence *compact* by the Heine-Borel Theorem in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

---

Here is where my question is. How do we show
$$m_*(A\cup B) = m_*(A)+m_*(B)$$
when $A$ and $B$ are *compact* and *disjoint*?

---

My attempt at this proof in outline form:
Take any covering by closed cubes for the union $A\cup B$ and find a refinement which consists of disjoint closed cubes (almost disjoint?) and each of which only contains $A$ or $B$ but not both (provided by $A\cap B=\emptyset$). Compactness then allows us to find a finite subcover of this refinement.

So we can reduce the problem of finding the infimum of total volumes (i.e. $m_*(A\cup B)$) for arbitrary covers of the union to that of *finite coverings by almost disjoint, closed cubes, with the above strict containment*. Then argue that this is just $m_*(A)+m_*(B)$ and we're done. The last line is had by re-arranging the sum of volumes (which we can do since the sum is finite).

---

I'm not sure if what I have here is correct, I'm looking for some peer review or an alternative proof! The authors gloss over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are compact and disjoint, then $d(A, B) > 0$. So it suffices to show that if $S_1, S_2 \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $d(S_1, S_2) > 0$, then $m_*(S_1 \cup S_2) = m_*(S_1) + m_*(S_2)$.

If $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, then I claim that $m_*(E) = \inf\{m_*(O) : O \subset \mathbb{R}^n \text{ open }, O \supset E\}$. This can be proved by using the fact that any open $O \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a countable union of almost disjoint closed cubes and that $m_*(O)$ is the sum of the volumes of these cubes (here is where Heine Borel is used).

From this it follows that if $O_1$ and $O_2$ are disjoint, then $m_*(O_1 \cup O_2) = m_*(O_1) + m_*(O_2)$. Now the proof for $m_*(S_1 \cup S_2) \geq m_*(S_1) + m_*(S_2)$ is done easily: given $O \supset S_1 \cup S_2$, let $$O_j = O \cap \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : d(x, S_j) < \frac{d(S_1, S_2)}{2}\}.$$
Note that $O_1, O_2$ are disjoint. Thus $m_*(O) \geq m_*(O_1 \cup O_2) = m_*(O_1) + m_*(O_2) \geq m_*(S_1) + m_*(S_2)$. Taking the inf over $O \supset S_1 \cup S_2$ yields $m_*(S_1 \cup S_2) \geq m_*(S_1) + m_*(S_2)$. This argument is actually essentially the same as yours, replacing refinement by taking intersections.

Comment: It seems you refine $O$ into $O_1\cup O_2$ and argue containment with $d(S_1,S_2)>0$. Applying Monotonicity a couple times and then infimum for the win. The part about representing open sets with countable unions of a.d. closed cubes I've seen previously in the text (Thm 1.4, pg.7). Not sure about H-B involvement, but ignoring that it seems you boil the argument down to ~"From [alt. $m_*$ def] it follows that if $O_1$ and $O_2$ disjoint, then $m_*(O_1\cup O_2)$ separates." I am convinced! Thank you

Comment: @kevinS The Heine Borel theorem is used to prove that the outer measure of an open set is the sum of the volumes of the almost disjoint cubes. If you go through the details for that proof you will see how it is used. It isn't obvious how it is used from just what I wrote.